# JQuery how to stop event propagation

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, stoppropagation, event-propagation

I'm looking to stop the event from propagating so that every time I click "done", the alert only shows up **once**.

Here is my code:

```
$('body').on('click', '#product', function () {

    var x = "hi";
    $('#done').click(function () {
        alert(x);
    });

});
```

And the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s4sz29ew/1/

Comment: You can use `one` to bind event on `#done`. Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/s4sz29ew/2/).

Comment: What's wrong with `$('body').on('click', '#done', funct...`?

Comment: @Tushar one is what did the trick for me. I tried all the answers and nothing worked but yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', '#product', function () {

    var x = "hi";
    $('#done').click(function (e) {
        alert(x);
e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is what you are looking for :

```
$('body').on('click', '#product', function () {

 var x = "hi";
 $('#done').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(x);
  });

});
```

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. above code looks bit weird to me : If you want to watch #done click then use on this id only

```
 $('body').on('click', '#done', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('test');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use event.stopPropagation();
It will stop the event from bubling up the DOM.

See: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean flag 'buttonclicked', and mark it true, when the button is clicked and then and use an

```
var buttonclicked = false;    
$('body').on('click', '#product', function () {

       var x = "hi";

       $('#done').click(function () {
           if(buttonclicked) {
              return;
           } else {
              alert(x);
              buttonclicked = true;
           }
       });

});
```